# Efficiently eliminating rows in a dataframe based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframes:

```
df_1 =
userId     itemId     rating
a          i1         0
b          i2         1
b          i3         0
b          i4         1
c          i4         1


df_2 =
itemId    info1     info2
i1        30        0
i2        20        1
i3        20        0
```

I want to eliminate the rows in the first dataframe that contain `itemId`s which don't appear in the second dataframe, so in this case, `i4` doesn't appear so my new dataframe would be:

```
 userId     itemId     rating
 a          i1         0
 b          i2         1
 b          i3         0
```

What I tried: I merged the two and then deleted the columns `info1` and `info2`. I find it unsafe because my dataframes are huge and the same `itemId` appears several times in `df_1`. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `df_1.merge(df_2['itemId'])` will be a perfectly safe answer as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
df_1[df_1['itemId'].isin(df_2['itemId'])]
```

Explanation:

`df_1['itemId'].isin(df_2['itemId'])` will generate a *boolean* based on if an `itemId` is present in `df_2` or not and then we will pass that boolean to the `df_1` to get the entries in `df_1` with `itemId` present in `df_2`